# Перемещение элемента по целочисленным значениям input

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

я задал функцией передвижение элемента по x таким образом:

```
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
            slider.oninput = function() {
                rootar1.position.x = parseInt($('myRange').value);
            }
```

но у меня он не ползает по шагу инпута(шаг равен 0.01), то есть, при введении целочисленного значения в инпут, объект двигается, а при введении дробного значения, нет, как решить эту проблему???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parseInt`, эта функция может принимать дробное число в виде строки и возвращает спарсенное целое число без дробной части.

Например `var decimal = parseInt("15.99");` вернет 15, а в вашем случае эта функция принимает дробное число < 1, и что логично возвращает 0.

Чтобы ваш объект менял свою позицию, нужно значение `myRange` парсить в вещественное число, например функцией `parseFloat`.

```
rootar1.position.x = parseFloat($('myRange').value);
```

Comment: типо библиотека dat gui использует что-то на подобии сочетания inout Range и обычного цифрового инпута, и там можно вводить нецелочисленные значения, и объект будет менять своё местоположение, я хочу сделать тоже самое, но используя так сказать подручные средства

Comment: Пасибо большое, я запомню что ты для меня сделал, твоя помощь не останется без внимания, я тебе это гарантирую.